# Vue append element with some questions

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code, and i try to get fruit1 and fruit2 input, but got [object Object] or undefined with alert(this.inputs.id) or alert(this.inputs).

```
<div id="item">
    <div v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.id">
        <label :for="input.id">{{input.label}}</label>
        <input :id="input.id" v-model="input.value"></input>
    </div>
    <button @click="addInput">Add input</button>
</div>

data() {
    return {
        counter: 1,
        inputs: [{
            id: 'fruit1',
            label: 'Enter Fruit Name',
            value: '123',
        }],
    }
}

addInput() {
    this.inputs.push({
        id: `fruit${++this.counter}`,
        label: 'Enter Fruit Name',
        value: '',
    });
}
```

Comment: this.inputs is an array not object, you can't call this.inputs.id, but this.inputs[0].id

Comment: Where are you trying to call alert()?

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius I got it, many thanks with your answer this.inputs[1].id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addInput` should be put on `methods`

`this.inputs` is an array not object, you can't call `this.inputs.id`, you should do `this.inputs[0].id` instead

if you want to get certain input by providing the id, you can do this

```
methods: {
    addInput() {
        this.inputs.push({
            id: `fruit${++this.counter}`,
            label: 'Enter Fruit Name',
            value: '',
        });
    },
    getInput(id) {
        return this.inputs.find(input => {
            return input.id === id
        }
    }
}
```